# Trouble installing coffee-script with npm

Tags: macos, coffeescript, npm

Here is my console output after running sudo npm install -g coffee-script

```
Joshuas-MacBook-Pro-2:~ jwalsh$ sudo npm install -g coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm WARN package.json @0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @0.0.0 No readme data.
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/coffee -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/cake -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake
npm WARN package.json cli-table@0.2.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json cheerio-select@0.0.3 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json eyes@0.1.8 No repository field.
coffee-script@1.6.2 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script
```

coffee-script does not install correctly.  Is my path correct?

Comment: Why do you say it is not installed correctly? What does not work?

Comment: The command to run in order to execute Coffeescript is "coffee" alone. Can you tell us more about your issues?